Any help on replacing refrigerator door gasket
Kenmore Coldspot 106.51179310
This is a french door type of fridge with the freezer on the left and the fresh food on the right.
Fresh food side doesn't get cold enough. Dollar bill test shows it doesn't seal for about a foot either way of the bottom left corner. Also there seems to be a tear in the gasket along the bottom edge. I have a replacement gasket on hand. I'll replace it, but does the dollar bill test also indicate that the door isn't square somehow? Also, any removal / installation tips highly appreciated. I can't get the darn thing out like they do in an online video. There are no screws, it's press-fit. Thank you.

there are two hinges. top and bottom. those can be adjusted
